# Flex Force Uppercase in ComboBox

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, uppercase

I am trying to force uppercase in some ComboBox

```
<s:ComboBox id="cbStocks" width="200" height="30" fontSize="16" dataProvider="{this.knownSymbols}" />
```

I tried the setStyle approach suggested by [flexexamples](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/01/26/setting-the-typographic-case-on-a-spark-label-control-in-flex-4/) without success

```
cbStocks.setStyle( "typographicCase", TypographicCase.CAPS);
```

and

```
cbStocks.textInput.setStyle( "typographicCase", TypographicCase.CAPS);
```

both throw an exception

```
RangeError: Property typographicCase value caps is out of range
```

**How do you force Uppercase in a ComboBox?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom formatter to achieve this:

```
public class CapsFormatter extends Formatter {

    override public function format(value:Object):String {
        return value ? value.toString().toUpperCase() : "";
    }

}
```

and then use it as follows:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <f:CapsFormatter id="capsFormatter"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:ComboBox labelFunction="capsFormatter.format">
    <s:ArrayList>
        <fx:String>Hello</fx:String>
        <fx:String>world</fx:String>
    </s:ArrayList>
</s:ComboBox>
```